# Match only if all characters in a set are present

Tags: regex, perl

Character classes like `/[abcde]/` are great when you want to match *any* character in the class, but I want to enforce that *all* characters in the set should be present, regardless of the order they appear in.

So if my set comprises of `abcde` the regex should:

- successfully match strings like `"ascribed"`, `"cheeseboard"`, and `"eradicable"`
- fail to match `"vibrance"`, `"yeti"` and `"wishful"`

---

I do have a working solution that involves use of multiple lookahead assertions:

```
/(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d)(?=.*e)/
```

but wonder if there are alternatives to this.

It doesn't look too bad if you're coding this by hand.

However, if you want to parametrize it to an arbitrary set of characters it requires you to write a sub that generates a suitable regex. I guess that the generalizability of my current approach is what I'm not so keen on.

Comment: This is not an ideal job for regular expressions. While you can make it work in limited cases, you're really just looking for a Boolean result. Ruby makes this easy; consider `%w[a b c d e].map { |char| "ascribed".match char }.all?` as an example that returns true, while matching "ascried" (without the letter "b") will return false.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Readability matters.**

```
/a/ && /b/ && /c/ && /d/ && /e/
```

This is possibly a little bit slower than some of the solutions below. But speed isn't everything, especially if both alternatives are quite fast.

Readability and maintainability are usually far more important, and this is clearly far more readable and maintainable than the original.

---

Still, I'll continue with other alternatives.

First of all, we can micro-optimize what you have:

```
/^(?=.*a)(?=.*b)(?=.*c)(?=.*d).*e/s
```

This eliminates a serious amount of backtracking when the pattern doesn't match, and it probably even speeds up positive matches by not checking for line feeds.

Even faster,

```
/^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c)(?=.*?d).*?e/s
```

---

For strings to match literally, though, using `index` instead of the regex engine should be faster.

```
my @strs = qw( a b c d e );
my $str = $_;
@strs == grep { index($str, $_) >= 0 } @strs
```

```
use List::Util qw( all );
my @strs = qw( a b c d e );
my $str = $_;
all { index($str, $_) >= 0 } @strs
```

---

An approach that works well for a dynamic list of characters:

```
my @chars = qw( a b c d e );
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for unpack '(a)*', $_;
@chars == grep { $counts{$_} } @chars
```

```
use List::Util qw( all );
my @chars = qw( a b c d e );
my %counts;
++$counts{$_} for unpack '(a)*', $_;
all { $counts{$_} } @chars
```

The downside is that this doesn't short circuit. It still needs to process the entire string even if it starts with `abcde`.

---

If you have a dynamic list of patterns, you can still use some of the earlier approaches.

```
# /^(?=.*?a)(?=.*?b)(?=.*?c)(?=.*?d).*?e/s
my $pat = join "", map { "(?=.*?$_)" } @pats;
my $re = qr/^$pat/s;
/$re/
```

```
# /a/ && /b/ && /c/ && /d/ && /e/
my $str = $_;
@pats == grep { $str =~ /$_/ } @pats
```

```
# /a/ && /b/ && /c/ && /d/ && /e/
use List::Util qw( all );
my $str = $_;
all { $str =~ /$_/ } @pats
```

Answer (score 2):

I would go with multiple patterns and match for all of them, as that is much easier to read. Most of the time in my opinion the simplest way is the best.

Stick the patterns in an array and use `all` from [List::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::Util#all).

```perl
use feature 'say';
use List::Util 'all';

my @patterns = (qr/a/, qr/b/, qr/c/, qr/d/, qr/e/);

foreach my $word (qw(ascribed cheeseboard eradicable vibrance yeti wishful)) {
    say $word if all { $word =~ $_ } @patterns;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following script accepts one word per line from standard input and prints the ones which have all the characters present in the first argument.
Save script in file named `has_all_chr.pl` and run like `cat words | perl has_all_chr.pl abcde`. You can easily adapt it for your requirement.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use List::Util;

my @c = List::Util::uniq( split "", shift ); 
#unique characters to look for in words

my @in = <>;
chomp @in;

for my $word (@in) {

    next if length $word < @c;
    #reject if word is too short to contain all characters

    print "$word\n" if List::Util::all { -1 != index $word, $_ } @c; 
    #all chrs must be present
}
```

If the file `words` has:

```
ascribed
cheeseboard
eradicable
vibrance
yeti
wishful
```

then the output is

```
ascribed
cheeseboard
eradicable
```

Answer (score 1):

you can capture all the matches as a string then match that against your key

```
perl -le '$x = "cheeseboard"; $r = join "", sort ($x =~ /[abcde]/g); print $r =~ /a+b+c+d+e+/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could bind the expression to the very start of the string and use the principle of contrast:

```
^(?=[^a]*a)(?=[^b]*b)(?=[^c]*c)(?=[^d]*d)(?=[^e]*e).+
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/S0Dr1y/1/).

Comment: I was looking for alternatives... this is equivalent to what was posted in the question

Comment: @Zaid; this is wayyyyy more efficient than what is mentioned in the question and one of the preferred way too. Please read [**this**](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast)

Comment: You're completely missing the point, this is fundamentally the same approach

Comment: @Mandy8055, The leading `^` does make it far more efficient, but the answer goes far beyond that.1) I doubt the other changes necessarily help. (I suspect it depends on internal storage formats of the string and pattern.) 2) You could get the same benefit from using `/s` and `.*?` instead of `[^a]*`, which is visually simpler, and 3) the added trailing `.+` is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Mandy8055: It surely is more efficient, thanks for that. Albeit it is a regex approach because it was tagged with `regex` - another approach not using lookaheads won't work imo.

Comment: @ikegami: Not only because of the `^` but also because of the negations, `[^a]*a` is almost always more efficient thant `.*a`. The latter brings you down the line but needs to backtrack.

Comment: @Jan, I already covered that. Did you just read the first sentence of my comment?

Comment: @ikegami: No, I did read all of it. Isn't `.*?` more "expensive" than e.g. `[not_this]*this` ? See https://regex101.com/r/hiiFu7/1 vs https://regex101.com/r/hiiFu7/2 - 53 vs 9 steps.

Comment: I agree with you too @Zaid; that it is fundamentally the same; but this answer by no fair means is subject to a downvote. It is completely your choice if you accept it or not but downvoting IMHO kills the beauty of the concept. This is my belief although. Please don't get me wrong.

Comment: @Jan, You're not testing with the right regex engine. This is a Perl question, not a PCRE question. And you left out the `/s`. (How do you get it to list the steps, btw?)

Comment: @Mandy8055 The green box doesn't do anything for me, but the regex debugger link did the tricks. Its count of steps is useless. It counts doing "Is the next character an a?" 10 times 10 steps in one pattern and 1 step in the other pattern. That means the steps are totally useless metric for comparing performance.

Comment: @Mandy8055, And since this is a Perl question, not a PCRE question, here's the actual relevant information: [Output from Perl](https://pastebin.com/i7jn5FfN)  47 vs 47 opcodes, and 7 vs 9 steps

Comment: (Note that I didn't downvote. The explanation given --that adding `^` really helps-- is correct. But a correct fact doesn't make a good answer.)

Comment: @Mandy8055, It can be an indicator of a performance problem, but you can't tell if it is or not, so you can't trust it. It's like distance traveled is no indicator of displacement. Saying I walked 1 km might indicate I ended up 1 km away from where I started, but maybe I walked in a circle. I'll conceded that it can be used as indicator to look deeper.