# GREP: Find words containing multiple specific characters

Tags: grep

To clarify a bit, while I am aware how to grab words with a single specific character, I'm unsure how to approach looking for multiple of them. For example, what grep command would be used to retrieve only the words containing both "b" **and** "p" (in any order), not just one or the other?

Using the above example, if you're given words like "bear," "pear," "biography," and "printable," it would only return the last two words. These are some of my previous attempts.

```
grep -E "\b[bp]\b" input
grep -E "\b(b|p)\b" input
grep -E "\bb.*p\b" input
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: @Cyrus My bad, just added the edits!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62717489/match-only-if-all-characters-in-a-set-are-present

Comment: @kvantour This is in the right step, but I'm hoping to do it all in a single grep command.

Comment: `grep -E '\w*(p\w*b|b\w*p)\w*'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do it with a regular expression. For instance, here the code snippet for your problem.

```bash
grep '\w*[b]\w*[p]\w*\|\w*[p]\w*[b]\w*' test.txt
```

Helpful links to read further:

- https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/grep-regular-expressions/
- https://regexr.com/

Comment: Unfortunately this still only gives me words containing one or the other, but I only want words containing both letters.

Comment: I have updated my answer to match your requirements.